# Which package version am I using?

Tags: packages

Is there a LaTeX command for printing the versions of the currently installed packages? I need to know the installed version of the `pgfplots` package.

Comment: with vanilla TeXLive distro, On command line/Terminal invoking `tlmgr info pgfplots` gives the version of pgfplots installed.

Comment: See also: [distributions - Automatically Determine which TeXLive Version is being used - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96570/automatically-determine-which-texlive-version-is-being-used) --  [tex core - Detecting which version of the LaTeX format is in use - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26178/detecting-which-version-of-the-latex-format-is-in-use) -- [`@ifpackageloaded`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16199/test-if-a-package-or-package-option-is-loaded)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Add `\listfiles` to your preamble and then look at the `.log` file. This will tell you the current version of all the packages loaded.

Comment: Package versions are announced in the `.log` file even without `\listfiles`.

Comment: @Andrey: makes them easier to find, thought :-)

Comment: It might be interesting to write a command line tool to check that.

Comment: @ℝaphink I have attempted, but the fact that TeX hard-wraps the output makes it very difficult.

Comment: @SeanAllred You can increase `max_print_line` in `texmf.cnf` to have it (practically) not wrap; see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52988/avoid-linebreaks-in-latex-console-log-output).

Comment: If using pdfLatex, within the log output the result of \listfiles starts with the line *File List*

Comment: Won't it be even better to add `\listfiles` in the very beginning of the file, even before `\documentclass`?

Answer (score 64):

If you need to know this 'programmatically', then you can use the LaTeX kernel function `\IfPackageAtLeast` to test by date:

```
\IfPackageAtLeast{<package>}{2011/03/13}
  {%
    % Do something for the newer version
  }
  {%
    % Do something different for the older version
  }%
```

The information is stored inside a special macro, so if you just want to 'take a peek' you can use that. Taking `pgfplots` as an example

```
\expandafter\show\csname ver@pgfplots.sty\endcsname
```

Notice here that this needs the *full* file name we are interested in, so works for any file that contains suitable information (*i.e.* form `\ProvidesPackage`, `\ProvidesClass` or `\ProvidesFile`).

Comment: you can load the name into a macro by `\edef\foo{\csname ver@pgfplots.sty\endcsname}`

Comment: Nowadays it can be accessed with the name `\IfPackageAtLeastTF`. (documentation at no-idea-where, source code in source2e.pdf.)

Comment: Remark, if `<package>` happens to be `expl3` then [it only work after explicit `\usepackage{expl3}` even in versions where expl3 are available by default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/609962/250119). Before loading it, it's in `ExplFileDate` or the (internal, do not use) `\c__kernel_expl_date_tl`

Answer (score 1):

To find a package version, you can just open the package source file on your file system and look the version directly by yourself with some text editor as Sublime Text.

Here are the paths and references for the latex paths on Linux and Windows for the `biblatex` package:

1. Miktex (Windows) `D:\Programs\Mikyex\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex-abnt\bbx\abnt.bbx`

   - [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)
   - On the file `abnt.bbx`, you will find this at his top, , where the version is: `v3.1`

   ```
   ...
   \ProvidesFile{abnt.bbx}%
   [2017/07/28\space v3.1\space ABNT BibLaTeX citation style]%
   ...
   ```
2. TeX Live (Linux) `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-abnt/abnt.bbx`

   - https://askubuntu.com/questions/296681/latex-filepaths-in-ubuntu
   - On the file `abnt.bbx`, you will find this at his top, where the version is: `v3.2`

   ```
   ...
   \ProvidesFile{abnt.bbx}%
   [2017/11/09\space v3.2\space ABNT BibLaTeX citation style]%
   ...
   ```

Comment: note you should check the files using the paths reported by tex in the log not "reference" paths as above. The most common issues for which people need to check versions is where they have multiple tex installations and tex is not using the package they think it is using (eg miktex user and admin installs, or  linux tex and a vanilla texlive from tug etc) So the important question is not do you have the latest version of the package installed, it is is your tex using that version.