# How do I find which pgf version I have installed on Windows (MikTeX)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, miktex, windows

I'm not sure how to find which version of `pgf` with MikTeX installed on my computer (Windows 7 - 64 bit).

Comment: Just use `\pgfversion` in a minimal and you will see it.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the general question [Which package version am I using?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/2975). If this doesn't help you, please update your question and mentioned why. It it's solving your problem we will close this as a duplicate to keep the site tidy.

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides Thanks, `\pgfversion` works, and is much simpler than reading the log.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks to Yiannis Lazarides:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}

My pgf version is: \pgfversion

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you put `\listfiles` a the beginning of your document, the list of loaded packages will appear in the log (and probably in your console display.)

The current version of tikz/pgf is:

```
 tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
 pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
```

(TeXLive 2010)

If your MikTeX is recently updated, it is probably the same.  If you *have* upated your MikTeX, and the version numbers don't match, then you may have a version of pgf in your local texmf folder.  You can tell this by looking in the log file.  As each package is loaded the log will reflect the full path to the file.

e.g.

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
```

(These are the paths for TeXLive; MikTeX will be different, but there should be consistency between these paths and e.g. the path of `article.cls`).

Answer (score 2):

`MiKTeX` has a package manager, you could go to `Start->Program->MiKTeX->Maintenance(Admin)->Package Manager`, enter the name of the package in the search bar to retrieve the information of it.

Comment: The package manager doesn't list version numbers