# Debugging texlive-pgf sources

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlive, linux

I've recently changed operating systems (from Ubuntu 14.04 to Fedora 22) and this means in particular that I now have a newer version of the pgf package. To be precise, it is this version: `texlive-pgf-svn33057.3.0.0-8.fc22.noarch` (and [`\pgfversion`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15402/how-do-i-find-which-pgf-version-i-have-installed-on-windows-miktex) shows 3.00), while my Ubuntu had `\pgfversion` 2.10. Compiling my older papers, I keep encountering the following:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65
.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18
.sty)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers
.code.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.24 \pgfdeclareplothandler
                           {\pgfplothandlercurveto}{}{%
? X
No pages of output.
Transcript written on subjective-logic.log.
```

I tried to find documentation on this error, but I haven't found any that actually relate to this particular control sequence. First I thought a package was just missing, but I've tried to install all available texlive-tikz packages and pgf-related packages, and also removing all except for texlive-pgf, but none of this seems to help. Using `rpm -qf`, I determined that the file mentioned above is indeed part of the texlive-pgf package. A colleague of mine, who is also running Fedora 22, can compile the same documents without issues. I'm not really sure how to narrow down this problem any further. I did try to create a minimal example; I took [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/graph/) and narrowed it down to this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[main node] (1) {1};
  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
        edge [loop above] node {0.1} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I did do a quick search to see whether I could find where pgflibraryplothandlers should be defined, which gave me the following output:

```
$grep -r 'pgflibraryplothandlers'  /usr/share/texlive/
/usr/share/texlive/texlive.tlpdb: RELOC/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
/usr/share/texlive/texlive.tlpdb: RELOC/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
/usr/share/texlive/texlive.tlpdb: RELOC/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgflibraryplothandlers.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex:\ProvidesFileRCS[v\pgfversion] $Header: /cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex,v 1.20 2013/08/31 13:02:59 ludewich Exp $
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex:% More handlers are defined in pgflibraryplothandlers
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgflibraryplothandlers.sty:\input{pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex}
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/ls-R:pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/ls-R:pgflibraryplothandlers.sty
```

Could it be that something changed in the way TeX searches for files, and that my stuff in `~/texmf` is causing problems?

Comment: Normally this shouldn't be a problem since `plothandler` was also a library in TikZ 2.10 if I remember correctly. I think subfolders are not mapped and TikZ v3 is searching the libraries in the TikZ 2.10 path.

Comment: @percusse as far as I understand, there's only 3.0 sources on this machine, except for the ~/texmf folder, which was copied from the old machine (it contains a few university templates). Should I try removing that, or is there a more appropriate location to put such material?

Comment: Actually, you just solved my problem. Looks like one of those templates messes with what is presumably older TiKZ code, which was located in my `~/texmf` folder. Thanks!

Comment: Ah great, glad that triggered some ideas. Do you mind if we close this question since it is a local problem to your own setting?

Comment: yeah, that's fine, I'm just not sure how to do that :-).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a no-repro after resolving the conflicting custom templates path.