# mdframed undefined sequence

Tags: mdframed

I implemented the `mdframed` package and I wanted to create a new envrionment, but I get the following error message:

```
Writing index file book.idx
! Undefined control sequence.
l.80 \newmdtheoremenv
                     [hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=shadethmcolor,skipab...
```

here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{left=4cm,right=3cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

% choose options for [] as required from the list
% in the Reference Guide
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
%,bookmarksopenlevel={1}
%\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,]{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,bookmarksopen=false,
hypertexnames=TRUE,pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}[2011/02/05]
\hypersetup{ 
  pdftitle={Statistik},
  pdfauthor={\textcopyright test test},
  pdfsubject={}, 
  pdfkeywords={}, 
  }

\usepackage{xcolor,bookmark}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{courier}


\usepackage{type1cm}         
\usepackage{zref-abspage}



\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation

\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot} 
%\usepackage{thmbox}
%\usepackage{shadethm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{marginnote}
%\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style svind.ist with
                       % your makeindex program

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

%%%%%Umgebungen%%%%%
%\theoremstyle{plain}
%\theoremstyle{remark}
%\newtheorem{beispiel}{Beispiel}[chapter]

\definecolor{shadethmcolor}{rgb}{.9,.9,.95}%
\definecolor{shadethmcolor2}{rgb}{1,.925,.545}%

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}{}{}%
  {\bfseries}{:}{.5em}{}%

\theoremstyle{mystyle}

\newmdtheoremenv[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=shadethmcolor,skipabove=\topsep,
skipbelow=\topsep]{beispiel}{Beispiel}

\begin{document}
\begin{beispiel}
test test
\end{beispiel}
\end{document}
```

---

```
*File List*
    book.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    bk10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
titlesec.sty    2007/08/12 v2.8 Sectioning titles
   babel.sty    2008/07/06 v3.8l The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
ngermanb.ldf    2008/07/06 v2.6n new German support from the babel system
mathptmx.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Times w/ Math, improved (SPQR, WaS) 
  helvet.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS) 
wallpaper.sty    2005/01/18, v1.01 easy wallpaper formatting (MHFW)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 eso-pic.sty    2010/10/06 v2.0c eso-pic (RN)
atbegshi.sty    2011/01/30 v1.15 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pdfpages.sty    2011/03/10 v0.4n Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)
pppdftex.def    2011/03/10 v0.4n Pdfpages driver for pdfTeX (AM)
hyperref.sty    2011/04/17 v6.82g Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Subsetting bundle oberdiek (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.13 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Defining keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/04/04 v1.12 Provides string conversions (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Expandable big integer calculations (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Data type bit set (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provides unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/01/30 v1.0 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/04/23 v1.7 Hooks at very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2010/12/01 v3.2 Data extraction from references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2010/12/23 v3.10 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2011/04/17 v6.82g Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2011/04/17 v6.82g Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
bookmark.sty    2011/04/21 v1.21 PDF bookmarks (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
bkm-pdftex.def    2011/04/21 v1.21 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
scrextend.sty    2011/04/02 v3.09 KOMA-Script KOMA-Script package (extend other
 classes with features of KOMA-Script classes)
scrkbase.sty    2011/04/02 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2011/04/02 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
scrlfile.sty    2011/03/09 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
titlepic.sty    2009/08/03 1.1 Package to display a picture on the title page
shorttoc.sty    2002/08/20 v1.3 Short table of contents (JPFD)
 courier.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS) 
 type1cm.sty    2002/09/05 v0.04 BlueSky/Y&Y Type1 CM font definitions (DPC, pa
tched RF)
zref-abspage.sty    2011/03/18 v2.21 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2011/03/18 v2.21 Module base for zref (HO)
 makeidx.sty    2000/03/29 v1.0m Standard LaTeX package
multicol.sty    2008/12/05 v1.6h multicolumn formatting (FMi)
footmisc.sty    2009/09/15 v5.5a a miscellany of footnote facilities
tocstyle.sty    2009/11/09 v0.2d-alpha LaTeX2e KOMA-Script package (versatile t
oc styles)
shadethm.sty    1999/11/23
  amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20
 amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
marginnote.sty    2010/01/05 v1.1f non floating margin notes for LaTeX
mdframed.sty    2010/12/22  v0.6a: mdframed
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
md-frame-0.mdf
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
supp-pdf.mkii
 nameref.sty    2010/04/30 v2.40 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
ot1ztmcm.fd    2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OT1/ztmcm.
omlztmcm.fd    2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OML/ztmcm.
omsztmcm.fd    2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OMS/ztmcm.
omxztmcm.fd    2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OMX/ztmcm.
   cover.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
   cover.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
  omsptm.fd    
   dedic.tex
foreword.tex
 preface.tex
  acknow.tex
 acronym.tex
  ot1phv.fd    2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv.
   part1.tex
chapter1.tex
ausrufezeichen.png    Graphic file (type png)
chapter2.tex
   part2.tex
chapter3.tex
chapter4.tex
appendix.tex
  ot1pcr.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/pcr.
    book.ind
ueberautor.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
ueberautor.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
    back.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
    back.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
 ***********
```

---

ok, its me again: here we go:
ok, so here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{left=4cm,right=3cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

% choose options for [] as required from the list
% in the Reference Guide
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
%,bookmarksopenlevel={1}
%\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,]{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,bookmarksopen=false,
hypertexnames=TRUE,pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}[2011/02/05]
\hypersetup{ 
  pdftitle={test},
  pdfauthor={\textcopyright test test},
  pdfsubject={test test}, 
  pdfkeywords={test}, 
  }

\usepackage{xcolor,bookmark}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{courier}


\usepackage{type1cm}         
\usepackage{zref-abspage}



\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation

\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot} 
%\usepackage{thmbox}
\usepackage{shadethm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{marginnote}
%\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style svind.ist with
                       % your makeindex program
\listfiles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

%%%%%Umgebungen%%%%%
%\theoremstyle{plain}
%\theoremstyle{remark}
%\newtheorem{beispiel}{Beispiel}[chapter]

%\definecolor{shadethmcolor}{rgb}{.9,.9,.95}%
%\definecolor{shadethmcolor2}{rgb}{1,.925,.545}%
%
%\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
%  {\topsep}{\topsep}{}{}%
%  {\bfseries}{:}{.5em}{}%
%
%\theoremstyle{mystyle}

%\newmdtheoremenv[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=shadethmcolor,skipabove=\topsep,
%skipbelow=\topsep]{beispiel}{Beispiel}
%
%\newmdtheoremenv[hidealllines=true,
%backgroundcolor=shadethmcolor2,skipabove=\topsep,
%skipbelow=\topsep]{formel}{Formel}
%



\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}{}{}%
  {\bfseries}{:}{.5em}{}%

\theoremstyle{mystyle}

\newshadetheorem{beispiele}{Beispiel}

\newenvironment{beispiel}[1][]{%
\par\vspace*{0cm}
  \definecolor{shadethmcolor}{rgb}{.9,.9,.95}%
  \definecolor{shaderulecolor}{rgb}{1,1,1}%
  \setlength{\shadeboxrule}{1.5pt}%
  \begin{beispiele}[#1]\hspace*{1mm}%
}{\end{beispiele}}

\newshadetheorem{formeln}{Formel}
\newenvironment{formel}[1][]{%
\par\vspace*{0cm}
  \definecolor{shadethmcolor}{rgb}{1,.925,.545}%
  \definecolor{shaderulecolor}{rgb}{1,1,1}%
  \setlength{\shadeboxrule}{1.5pt}%
  \begin{formeln}[#1]\hspace*{1mm}%
}{\end{formeln}}


\begin{document}
test test
\begin{beispiel}
test test
\end{beispiel}
\end{document}
```

and here is the list of all package versions in the log-file

```
*File List*
    book.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    bk10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
titlesec.sty    2007/08/12 v2.8 Sectioning titles
   babel.sty    2008/07/06 v3.8l The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
ngermanb.ldf    2008/07/06 v2.6n new German support from the babel system
mathptmx.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Times w/ Math, improved (SPQR, WaS) 
  helvet.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS) 
wallpaper.sty    2005/01/18, v1.01 easy wallpaper formatting (MHFW)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 eso-pic.sty    2010/10/06 v2.0c eso-pic (RN)
atbegshi.sty    2011/01/30 v1.15 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pdfpages.sty    2011/03/10 v0.4n Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)
pppdftex.def    2011/03/10 v0.4n Pdfpages driver for pdfTeX (AM)
hyperref.sty    2011/04/17 v6.82g Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Subsetting bundle oberdiek (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.13 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Defining keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/04/04 v1.12 Provides string conversions (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Expandable big integer calculations (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Data type bit set (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provides unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/01/30 v1.0 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/04/23 v1.7 Hooks at very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2010/12/01 v3.2 Data extraction from references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2010/12/23 v3.10 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2011/04/17 v6.82g Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2011/04/17 v6.82g Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
bookmark.sty    2011/04/21 v1.21 PDF bookmarks (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
bkm-pdftex.def    2011/04/21 v1.21 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
scrextend.sty    2011/04/02 v3.09 KOMA-Script KOMA-Script package (extend other
 classes with features of KOMA-Script classes)
scrkbase.sty    2011/04/02 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2011/04/02 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
scrlfile.sty    2011/03/09 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
titlepic.sty    2009/08/03 1.1 Package to display a picture on the title page
shorttoc.sty    2002/08/20 v1.3 Short table of contents (JPFD)
 courier.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS) 
 type1cm.sty    2002/09/05 v0.04 BlueSky/Y&Y Type1 CM font definitions (DPC, pa
tched RF)
zref-abspage.sty    2011/03/18 v2.21 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2011/03/18 v2.21 Module base for zref (HO)
 makeidx.sty    2000/03/29 v1.0m Standard LaTeX package
multicol.sty    2008/12/05 v1.6h multicolumn formatting (FMi)
footmisc.sty    2009/09/15 v5.5a a miscellany of footnote facilities
tocstyle.sty    2009/11/09 v0.2d-alpha LaTeX2e KOMA-Script package (versatile t
oc styles)
shadethm.sty    1999/11/23
  amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20
 amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
marginnote.sty    2010/01/05 v1.1f non floating margin notes for LaTeX
mdframed.sty    2010/12/22  v0.6a: mdframed
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
md-frame-0.mdf
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
supp-pdf.mkii
 nameref.sty    2010/04/30 v2.40 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
ot1ztmcm.fd    2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OT1/ztmcm.
omlztmcm.fd    2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OML/ztmcm.
omsztmcm.fd    2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OMS/ztmcm.
omxztmcm.fd    2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OMX/ztmcm.
   cover.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
   cover.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
  omsptm.fd    
   dedic.tex
foreword.tex
 preface.tex
  acknow.tex
 acronym.tex
  ot1phv.fd    2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv.
   part1.tex
chapter1.tex
ausrufezeichen.png    Graphic file (type png)
chapter2.tex
   part2.tex
chapter3.tex
chapter4.tex
appendix.tex
  ot1pcr.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/pcr.
    book.ind
ueberautor.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
ueberautor.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
    back.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
    back.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
 ***********
```

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 198.

LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.

well, I don't know which version of mdframed I am using?
I just said \usepackage{mdframed} ?

I heard about it from someone here, I used shade before for the environments but he said, I could get problems with page breaks and I should use mdframed......

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: Please add a `\listfiles` to your preamble and show us your output. I guess you are using an outdated version.

Comment: ok, I did it and I get the same output?

Writing index file book.idx
! Undefined control sequence.
l.80 \newmdtheoremenv
                     [hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=shadethmcolor,skipab...

my code: the same as above, I added \listfiles after \makeindex

Comment: Please outcommnent the problematic line, add `\listfiles` and run it again. Then a list of all package versions is listed in the `log-file`. Then please tell Marco which `mdframed` version your are using. BTW: how did you learn about `\newmdtheoremenv`, I guess the manual, but, did you read the manual from an online source, or from your own system?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/which-package-version-am-i-using

Comment: ok, so here is my code:

Comment: Needing to update versions is essentially 'too localized', as the problem is trivially fixed. I have closed as such.

Comment: BTW, you seem to have ended up with two separate accounts, so I've merged them.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the version 0.6 of mdframed. The current available version at CTAN is 1.6. So you see that you have an outdated version. I guess that all your packages are outdated.

**To solve the issue run your update manager.**