# Exam document class not leaving space for solutions when used with [noanswers]

Tags: exam

I'm attempting to use the exam document class to write an exam for my class, and for some reason this particular exam is not leaving space for their answers when I use the `[noanswers]` argument to the document class. Here is the markup:

```
\documentclass[noanswers]{exam}

% Additional LaTeX Packages

\usepackage{graphicx}

% Font and Typography Settings

\usepackage{beton}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{sbc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\headrule
\firstpageheader{CS 1411 -- Principles of Programming I}
    {Exam II}
    {Spring 2013}
\runningheader{CS 1411 -- Principles of Programming I}
    {Exam II, Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
    {Spring 2013}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question PROBLEM TEXT
\begin{parts}
\part function
\begin{solution}[\stretch{1}]
    PART A SOLUTION
\end{solution}

\part PART B
\begin{solution}[\stretch{1}]
    PART B SOLUTION
\end{solution}
\end{parts}

\question PROBLEM TEXT
\begin{parts}
\part PART A
\begin{solution}[\stretch{1}]
    PART A SOLUTION
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{Images/exam-2-problem-2.pdf}
    \end{center}
\end{solution}
\part PART B
\begin{solution}[\stretch{1}]
    PART B SOLUTION
\end{solution}
\end{parts}

\question PROBLEM TEXT
\begin{solution}[\stretch{1}]
\begin{verbatim}
PYTHON CODE IN VERBATIM MODE
\end{verbatim}
\end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Via `pdflatex` the generated PDF contains the solutions as I would expect when using the `[answers]` argument to the document class. Switching to `[noanswers]` simply prints the questions leaving no space for the solutions. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I get the expected result once a missing `\begin{questions}` is added just before the first `\question` command. Do you still get the problem mentioned after adding the missing command?

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, yes I still have the problem after adding the `\begin{questions}`. This was a copy/paste error in my working example. I'll update the code sample in the original post.

Comment: Perhaps it is then a problem of outdated packages(s)? Which version of the exam class are you using?

Comment: It works fine for me under `pdflatex` using `exam.cls` [version](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/which-package-version-am-i-using) `2011/05/22 Version 2.4 by Philip Hirschhorn`.  Try using `solutionorbox` -- you should see the space `exam` is making (or not making) for the solution.