# Algoritmic return command = 0

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

Can you suggest me what is wrong with using return command in algorithms.
when I add

```
\RETURN $C
```

to my LaTeX document I get

```
return C =0,
```

what I need is just `return C`.

```
\begin{algorithm}                      % enter the algorithm environment
  \caption{ lloyd's kmeans}      
  \label{alg1}                          
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]                    % enter the algorithmienvironment
    \RETURN{$C$}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

I get two extra characters `=0`. I wonder where its coming from.
if it helps,there is  "Missing number, treated as zero",and  Missing = inserted for \ifnum. in the error log generated

Comment: yes, i also checked it and it doesn't reproduce the problem when i run it alone. However, i still get the problem when I add it to my doc.

Comment: if it helps,there is "Missing number, treated as zero", in the error log generated

Comment: Do you define `\RETURN` somewhere else in your document? For example, what does `\show\RETURN` put in your `.log` when you place it just before this algorithm in your code? Also, what version of the packages are you using? You can find this out by following [Which package version am I using?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764)

Comment: @Werner yes, the problem still exists even after removing \return. i get =0 at end of my algo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably combining the use of [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) and [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package. The latter can be used as a full replacement of the former, so you should *not* load them together (the error is reproduced when they are loaded in sequence `\usepackage{algorithmic,algcompatible}`). I would suggest using it in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algcompatible}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

% Define keyword and construction of \RETURN
\algnewcommand\algorithmicreturn{\textbf{return}}
\algnewcommand\RETURN{\State \algorithmicreturn}%
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My algorithm}\label{alg1}                          
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \RETURN{} $C$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

This requires you to define the `\RETURN` keyword to function properly. There may be others as well that you need to define to work properly. However, they can be done in the same way.

---

Based on the [code you posted](http://pastebin.com/qDr1x9mZ), the following might be a way of defining your algorithm structures:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{algorithm,algcompatible}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{algorithms,algorithmicx}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicreturn{\textbf{return}}
\algnewcommand\RETURN{\algorithmicreturn}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicprocedure{\textbf{procedure}}
\algnewcommand\PROCEDURE{\item[\algorithmicprocedure]}%
\algnewcommand\algorithmicendprocedure{\textbf{end procedure}}
\algnewcommand\ENDPROCEDURE{\item[\algorithmicendprocedure]}%
\algnewcommand{\algvar}[1]{{\text{\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}}}}
\algnewcommand{\algarg}[1]{{\text{\ttfamily\itshape\detokenize{#1}}}}
\algnewcommand{\algproc}[1]{{\text{\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}}}}
\algnewcommand{\algassign}{\leftarrow}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}% enter the algorithm environment
\caption{procedure DOWNLOAD}% give the algorithm a caption
\label{SaS:DOWNLOAD}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]% enter the algorithmic environment
\raggedright
\PROCEDURE \algvar{user_request}(\algarg{follower_id}, \algarg{friend_id}, \algarg{content_id}, \algarg{home_server}, \algarg{friend_surrogate})
  \REQUIRE \algarg{user_id}, \algarg{home_server}
  \ENSURE URL of requested content
  \STATE $\algvar{content} \algassign \algproc{request_redirect}(\algarg{content_id})$
  \IF{$\algvar{content} \neq \algvar{server}$}
    \STATE \algproc{schedule_pull}(\algarg{content_id}, \algvar{server})
  \ENDIF
 \STATE \RETURN{} \algvar{content_host}
\ENDPROCEDURE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

In an attempt to be [consistent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764), define macros that would handle formatting of like items.

Comment: @warner thanks, but i get this error LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

Comment: @user14372: Can you post your entire algorithm somewhere (like [Pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com)? That way I could copy-and-paste it in my editor and try to replicate your problem (and help).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=WhWiMDDW

Comment: @user14372: I don't receive an error like that, although you may want to have `\REQUIRE $k \geq 0$
\STATE select k points as initial centroids`. Are you *only* loading [`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) and [`algcompatible`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) (not also [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms))?

Comment: I am working on existing document, and it loads the following
\usepackage[english]{babel} % o italian
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algcompatible}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
%%\usepackage{topfront}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}

Comment: @user14372: Remove the loading of `algorithmic`. Also, do you use `algpseudocode`? If not, remove that as well.

Comment: thanks for the follow up. i use algpseudocode to use procedure \Procedure{download}{$time, server$} . can you tell me a similar one, or help me define one for same goal.

Comment: @user14372: Look at the definitions within [`algpseudocode.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty) and copy them into your document preamble. [`algcompatible.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algcompatible.sty) does not define `\Procedure`. You may also wish to ask a [follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk)...

Comment: i Still get that annoying zero, please look at here http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=qDr1x9mZ

Comment: @user14372: I've added some code to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my code. I was using the `algpseudocode` package.

Original: Appends 0 at the end of return

```
\usepackage{algorithmic}               
\usepackage{algorithm}   
\usepackage{algpseudocode}  %This introduces extra zero at the end of algorithm
```

Solution: Does not append 0 at the end of return after removing the package `algpseudocode`:

```
\usepackage{algorithmic}            
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add an compilable tex code to your answer and an screenshot of your result too for a fast proof!

Comment: The algorithm and algorithmic (and algorithm2e, and...) packages serve more or less the same purpose, but give different look-and-feel, and will probably clash in internal implementation details, giving grief. For consistent look of your document(s), pick one (and live with it's quirks).

Comment: terrible answer this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed that error by placing the packages in the following order:

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{algorithmic} not required
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

Comment: This is a very old question which already has received an accepted answer, and what you're suggesting was already said above.