# why \end{algorithmic} ends with =0?

Tags: algorithms

I wrote some algorithms using pseudocode, but when compiling the document, each algorithm ends with =0 (at line\end{algorithmic}). What I have to do to avoid this problem?

Comment: Please add a small complete document that shows the problem. Hard to debug your code if we can not see it.

Comment: Don't combine the use of [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmic) with [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). See [Algoritmic return command = 0](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147619/5764). Use one *or* the other, but not both.