# Wrongly formatted algorithm in Latex

Tags: pdftex, algorithms

[image]

I am writing a paper in **latex** and there I am including **algorithm**. I added every package of an algorithm like

- `\usepackage{program}`
- `\usepackage{algorithm}`
- `\usepackage{algpseudocode}`
- `\usepackage{algorithmic}`
- `\usepackage[options ]{algorithm2e}`

I wrote `if else` with in `for loop` and that loop is written inside the body of **procedure** but its wrongly come.

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
\label{alg:euclid}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $U$: a set of authentic users
\State $T$: a set containing trustor and trustee information
    \Procedure{DepthDetection}{$T_{t_h}$, $U_i$}
    \State $T_{u_i} \gets$ list of trustee taking $U_i$ as trustor
    \State $I_{u_i} \gets$ list of items rated by $U_i$
    \State Build $U_i$'s trust network using $T_{t_h}$
    \For{each item $i$ in $I_{u_i}$}
    \State $NU_{u_i} \gets$ list of users who rated $I_i$
        \For{each user $u$ in $NU_{u_i}$ }
            \If{$u$ is in $T_{u_i}$}
                \State use the rating and trust of $u$ for prediction of rating
            \EndIf
        \EndFor
    \EndFor
    \State \textbf{return} $L$
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I managed to get the output of your photo, by loading some wrong combinations of packages. The correct packages used in my answer. When I got your output there was many latex errors in the code... Possibly you had the same. Even if the case is this, please upload the full code used for the output and just add that you get some errors (or the first error you get there)

Comment: Please next time post a complete document so that people can reproduce the problem and debug. Also if you get an error ask about the error message, the pdf output after an error is not intended to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the preamble packages combination I had to chose:

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{program}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{algpseudocode}
    %\usepackage{algorithmicx}
    %\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
\label{alg:euclid}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $U$: a set of authentic users
\State $T$: a set containing trustor and trustee information
    \Procedure{DepthDetection}{$T_{t_h}$, $U_i$}
    \State $T_{u_i} \gets$ list of trustee taking $U_i$ as trustor
    \State $I_{u_i} \gets$ list of items rated by $U_i$
    \State Build $U_i$'s trust network using $T_{t_h}$
    \For{each item $i$ in $I_{u_i}$}
    \State $NU_{u_i} \gets$ list of users who rated $I_i$
        \For{each user $u$ in $NU_{u_i}$ }
            \If{$u$ is in $T_{u_i}$}
                \State use the rating and trust of $u$ for prediction of rating
            \EndIf
        \EndFor
    \EndFor
    \State \textbf{return} $L$
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The above code gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much sir for helping. Please rate my question.

Comment: why coming 0 at the end of my algorithm?

Comment: I don't see any "0"... What exactly do you mean? Does it have to do with latex or with math? I am not used in using algorithms.

Comment: Now I completed my algorithm, everything coming fine but at the end "=0" is showing. I don't know why

Comment: I think that again you tried to make a wrong combination of packages. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147632/120578

Comment: Feel free to open a new question with the current code and your error ofcourse

Comment: Glad that helped... Welcome.