# Algorithm returning 0

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I wrote algorithms using the `algorithm` and `algorithmic` packages, but I always get the last line returning 0. I tried to use this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147619/algoritmic-return-command-0), but I could not make it work. Below my algorithm code and packages that I'm using.

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{nameref}% Only if hyperref isn't loaded
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[autostyle=false, style=english]{csquotes}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
  {% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
   \begin{center}
     \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
     \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
     \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
       {\raggedright\textbf{\ALG@name~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
       \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
       \else % #1 is not \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
       \fi
       \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
     }
  }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
     \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
   \end{center}
  }
\makeatother

\usepackage{booktabs, caption, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{footnote}

\begin{document}



     \begin{algorithm}[H] 
     \caption{EtHash mining algorithm}
     \begin{algorithmic}[1]
     \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
     \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
     \REQUIRE daggerset, params, block
     \ENSURE  nonce
      \STATE $nonce=randint(0,2$**$64)$
      \STATE $result = hashimoto(daggerset,$ \\ $get\_dagsize(params,block), params,$ \\ $decode\_int(block.prevhash), nonce);$
      \IF {$result * params$["diff"] $< 2$**$256$}
      \STATE $break;$
      \ENDIF
      \STATE $nonce = nonce + 1;$
      \IF {$nonce >= 2$**$64$}
      \STATE $nonce = 0;$
      \ENDIF

      \STATE $return$ $nonce;$
     \end{algorithmic}
     \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The output is this:

[image]

Comment: please complete your example so that it is compilable. if I add in `\documentclass{article}`, and the required `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`, I don't see the `=0`. so something else in your code must be causing this.

Comment: I've edited the original post.

Comment: Remove the loading of `algorithm2e` and `algpseudocode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `algorithm` and `algorithmic`; remove the loading of `algorithm2e` and of `algpseudocode`.