# What is the reason of extra '=0'

Tags: algorithms

I know the reason is the incompatibility of the packages, but I tried all the possibilities and I couldn't reach to the point of removing '=0' without changing the algorithm style I want. 
.

```
  \documentclass{IEEEtran}

  %\usepackage{algorithm}

  %\usepackage{algorithmicx}

  %\usepackage{algcompatible}


 \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

 \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx


 \usepackage{float}


 \begin{document}



 \begin{algorithm}

 \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}

 \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}

 \Input{The .}

 \Output{M $T$.}

 \Procedure {Update}{$Index, CurrentNode$}\\

 \eIf {$index$ not in $CurrentNode.MapTable$}{

 \begin{algorithmic}[1]

 \State Create a new entry in $CurrentNode.MapTable$\;

 \State Insert $index$ in the new entry\; 

 \State Create a new node $E$\;

 \State Create a new entry in the $CurrentNode.children$, correspond to
 previously created entry\;  

 \State Make the new entry point to E\;

 \State $E.parent$   $\leftarrow$ $CurrentNode$\;

 \State $CurrentNode$ $\leftarrow$ $E$\;

 \State Initialize $CurrentNode$ materialization and entries\;

 \end{algorithmic}

 }{

 \begin{algorithmic}[1]

 \State  Child pointed by\;

 \State Update \;

 \end{algorithmic}

 }

 \EndProcedure \\

 \For{$i\leftarrow 1$ \KwTo $N$}{

    \For{$l\leftarrow 1$ \KwTo $h$}{

         \State  $index [l]$  $\leftarrow$ generate index of data object $O_i$ 

 for level $l$ using $W_l$\;

    }        

    \eIf{$T.root$ is Null }{


       \State Create a $root$ node \;

    }{

       \State $CurrentNode$ =\ $root$ \;

        \CALL \textsc{Update}{$(Index, CurrentNode)$}\;

    }

     \For{$l\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $h-1$}{

            \CALL \textsc{Update}{$(Index, CurrentNode)$}\;

     }


 }

 \caption{Build}

 \end{algorithm}


 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Remove all `>` in the input, mark the code and press the curly braces in the input editor. That way the code gets proper highlighting.

Comment: Don't mix [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) and [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). Also see [Algoritmic return command = 0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147619/5764) (possible duplicate).

Comment: I saw this and don't solve my problem. But your answer is duplicate. I don't use 'algorithmicx'

Comment: @AboAliAlmusawi yes you do! `algpseudocode` is part of the `algorithmicx`package

Comment: I tried to use other packages to avoid using 'algorithm2e' and 'algorithmicx' together. But I lose other parts from the algorithm. It is a little bit complicated when I solve one issue other issues appear.