# I keep getting a bar and 0 at the end of the nested forall loop I write within a Pseudocode

Tags: algorithms, loops

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{foo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE let $S$ represent ..
\STATE let $P$ represent ..
\STATE let $N$ represent ..
\FORALL {$p \gets Rand(0,P) $}
\FORALL{$i \gets Rand(0,n)$} 
\STATE Select $j \gets Rand(0,n)$ \\
$S[p,j], S[p,i] \gets S[p,i], S[p,j]$
\ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information about your desired output, and please, *please* provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: That's probably `=0` at the end, which points to you mixing the use of [`algorithmic`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) (from the `algorithms` bundle) and `algorithmic` (from [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)). See [Algoritmic return command = 0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147619/5764).

Comment: the problem appeared to be that the \algpseudocode package was loaded and it was causing the code to return a zero at the end regardless.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you use the combination of the `algorithm` and `algorithmic` packages (this information was not provided in the question).

The syntax for `\FORALL` is that the definition of the loop variable is in brackets but the loop body is not in brackets. The body is assumed to be everything until the corresponding `\ENDFOR` statement.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.66\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{foo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE let $S$ represent ..
\STATE let $P$ represent ..
\STATE let $N$ represent ..
\FORALL{$p \gets Rand(0,P) $}
\FORALL{$i \gets Rand(0,n)$} 
\STATE Select $j \gets Rand(0,n)$ \\
$S[p,j], S[p,i] \gets S[p,i], S[p,j]$
\ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]