# Problem Creating a Polar Grid using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

I am a MacTeX 2013 user that uses PDFLaTeX to create my files. After a recent update, the following code stopped producing a polar grid. I checked the documentation for any changes as well as the change log. If I need to revert to an older version of one of my packages, I am not sure which ones need to be rolled back.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,letterpaper,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
\psaxes[axesstyle=polar,subticklinestyle=dashed,subticks=2,labelFontSize=\scriptstyle](3,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Can someone please help with what changes need to be made for the grid to appear with the update? If that's not possible, which packages should be rolled back to a previous version?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated comment: `pstricks` and `pstricks-add` are already loaded by `pst-all`.

Comment: I think it would be good for you to post the versions of the packages you're loading now. See [Which package version am I using?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764) (add `\listfiles` to your preamble and report back on what you find in the `.log`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,letterpaper,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
\psaxes[axesstyle=polar,subticklinestyle=dashed,subticks=2,
        labelFontSize=\scriptstyle](3,0)%%%% Radius,Angle
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The syntax is `(Radius,Angle)`. If Angle=0 then it is the same as 360.

With the degrees symbol:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\psvlabel#1{$\scriptstyle#1^\circ$}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar,subticklinestyle=dashed,subticks=2,
    labelFontSize=\scriptstyle](3,0)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to add  `{}^\circ` to the label? `xlabelFactor={}^\circ` and `ylabelFactor={}^\circ` do not work.

Comment: see edited answer. Will be changed in the package, probably ...

Comment: How to make the angle label on the right start from 0 instead of 360?