# How do I put a label to left of a horizontal ncline in psmatrix?

Tags: pst-node, psmatrix

The MWE example below does everything I want it to do, except the line

```
\tlput{$\delta$}
```

does nothing. I want the $\delta$ to the left of the dashed line.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \psmatrix[colsep=0.3cm,rowsep=.4cm,mnode=circle]
        [mnode=dot,dotscale=.00001] \\
        [mnode=dot,dotscale=.00001] & [mnode=dot,dotscale=.00001] & [mnode=dot,dotscale=.00001] \\
        [mnode=r] && [mnode=r]
        \ncline{1,1}{2,2}
        \taput{$\Pi$}
        \tlput{$M_{3}$}
        \ncline{2,2}{3,1}
        \tlput{$M_{1}$}
        \ncline{2,2}{3,3}
        \trput{$M_{2}$}
        \psset{linestyle=dashed}\ncline{2,1}{2,3}
        \tlput{$\delta$}
        \endpsmatrix
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I get [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z6Sk.png) when I compile your MWE as-is. The `\delta` is to the left of the dashed line. Perhaps you have some outdated packages? In order to see the package versions you're running with, see [Which package version am I using?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764) Then include the contents of `\listfiles` to your post. Alternatively, just [update your TeX distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764) completely, try again and report back.

Comment: I updated the pst-node package, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide us with your list of file versions by following the link I provided above.

Answer (score 1):

it also works with the shortcuts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

        \psmatrix[colsep=0.3cm,rowsep=.4cm,mnode=r]
         ~       \\
         ~& ~ &  \\
         ~&  ~& 
        \ncline{1,1}{2,2}^{$\Pi$}<{$M_{3}$}
        \ncline{2,2}{3,1}<{$M_{1}$}
        \ncline{2,2}{3,3}>{$M_{2}$}
        \ncline[linestyle=dashed]{2,1}{2,3}<{$\delta$}
        \endpsmatrix

\end{document}
```

`^`: above, `_`: below, `<`: left, and `>`: right

[image]

Comment: I've tried that, but the delta still doesn't appear for me.

Comment: What TeX-distribution do you have?