# Package babel error: Unknow option

Tags: babel

I just installed pdfTeX (Tex Live 2013/Debian) on by Ubuntu 13.10 laptop, but I have problems with the babel package.

My code:

```
\documentclass[12ptk a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}


 \begin{documenet}
  This is a test.
  \end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknow option 'danish'. Either you misspelled it or  the language definition file `danish.ldf` was not found.
```

My babel.sty file was found here `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel` and looks like this:

```
%%
%% This is file `babel.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% babel.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% This is a generated file.
%% 
%% Copyright 2012-2013 Javier Bezos and Johannes L. Braams.
%% Copyright 1989-2008 Johannes L. Braams and any individual authors
%% listed elsewhere in this file.  All rights reserved.
%% 
%% This file was generated from file(s) of the Babel system.
%% ---------------------------------------------------------
%% 
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%% 
%% The Current Maintainer of this work is Javier Bezos.
%% 
%% This file may only be distributed together with a copy of the Babel
%% system. You may however distribute the Babel system without
%% such generated files.
%% 
%% The list of all files belonging to the Babel distribution is
%% given in the file `manifest.bbl'. See also `legal.bbl for additional
%% information.
%% 
%% The list of derived (unpacked) files belonging to the distribution
%% and covered by LPPL is defined by the unpacking scripts (with
%% extension .ins) which are part of the distribution.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2005/12/01]
%% File 'babel.dtx'
%%\ProvidesFile{babel.dtx}[2013/05/16 v3.9f The Babel package]
%% Babel package for LaTeX2e.
%% Copyright (C) 1989 -- 2008 by Johannes Braams,
%%                            TeXniek
%%                            all rights reserved.
%% Copyright (C) 2013         by Johannes Braams
%%                            TeXniek
%%                            by Javier Bezos
%%                            all rights reserved.
\ProvidesPackage{babel}
    [2013/05/16 v3.9f %
     The Babel package]
\@ifpackagewith{babel}{debug}
  {\let\bbl@tempa\relax}
  {\def\bbl@tempa{3.9f}}%
\ifx\bbl@version\bbl@tempa\else
  \input switch.def\relax
\fi
\def\bbl@for#1#2#3{\@for#1:=#2\do{\ifx#1\@empty\else#3\fi}}
\def\bbl@add#1#2{%
  \@ifundefined{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}%
    {\def#1{#2}}%
    {\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}}
\def\bbl@csarg#1#2{\expandafter#1\csname bbl@#2\endcsname}%
\long\def\bbl@afterelse#1\else#2\fi{\fi#1}
\long\def\bbl@afterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}
\def\AfterBabelLanguage#1{%
  \global\expandafter\bbl@add\csname#1.ldf-h@@k\endcsname}%
\@ifpackagewith{babel}{base}{%
  \DeclareOption*{\bbl@patterns{\CurrentOption}}%
  \DeclareOption{base}{}%
  \ProcessOptions
  \global\expandafter\let\csname opt@babel.sty\endcsname\relax
  \global\expandafter\let\csname ver@babel.sty\endcsname\relax
  \global\let\@ifl@ter@@\@ifl@ter
  \def\@ifl@ter#1#2#3#4#5{\global\let\@ifl@ter\@ifl@ter@@}%
  \endinput}{}%
\bbl@csarg\let{tempa\expandafter}\csname opt@babel.sty\endcsname
\def\bbl@tempb#1.#2{%
   #1\ifx\@empty#2\else,\bbl@afterfi\bbl@tempb#2\fi}%
\def\bbl@tempd#1.#2\@nnil{%
  \ifx\@empty#2%
    \edef\bbl@tempc{\ifx\bbl@tempc\@empty\else\bbl@tempc,\fi#1}%
  \else
    \in@{=}{#1}\ifin@
      \edef\bbl@tempc{\ifx\bbl@tempc\@empty\else\bbl@tempc,\fi#1.#2}%
    \else
      \edef\bbl@tempc{\ifx\bbl@tempc\@empty\else\bbl@tempc,\fi#1}%
      \bbl@csarg\edef{mod@#1}{\bbl@tempb#2}%
    \fi
  \fi}
\let\bbl@tempc\@empty
\bbl@for\bbl@tempa\bbl@tempa{%
  \expandafter\bbl@tempd\bbl@tempa.\@empty\@nnil}
\expandafter\let\csname opt@babel.sty\endcsname\bbl@tempc
\DeclareOption{activeacute}{}
\DeclareOption{activegrave}{}
\DeclareOption{KeepShorthandsActive}{}
\DeclareOption{debug}{}
\DeclareOption{noconfigs}{}
\DeclareOption{showlanguages}{}
\DeclareOption{shorthands=off}{\bbl@tempa shorthands=\bbl@tempa}
\DeclareOption{strings}{\def\bbl@opt@strings{\BabelStringsDefault}}
\DeclareOption{strings=encoded}{\let\bbl@opt@strings\relax}
\DeclareOption{safe=none}{\let\bbl@opt@safe\@empty}
\DeclareOption{safe=bib}{\def\bbl@opt@safe{B}}
\DeclareOption{safe=ref}{\def\bbl@opt@safe{R}}
\DeclareOption{math=active}{}
\DeclareOption{math=normal}{\def\bbl@mathnormal{\noexpand\textormath}}
\def\BabelStringsDefault{generic}
\let\bbl@opt@shorthands\@nnil
\let\bbl@opt@config\@nnil
\let\bbl@opt@main\@nnil
\let\bbl@opt@strings\@nnil
\let\bbl@opt@headfoot\@nnil
\def\bbl@tempa#1=#2\bbl@tempa{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname bbl@opt@#1\endcsname\@nnil
    \expandafter\edef\csname bbl@opt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
  \else
    \bbl@error{%
      Bad option `#1=#2'. Either you have misspelled the\\%
      key or there is a previous setting of `#1'}{%
      Valid keys are `shorthands', `config', `strings', `main',\\%
      `headfoot', `safe', `math'}
  \fi}
\let\bbl@language@opts\@empty
\DeclareOption*{%
  \@expandtwoargs\in@{\string=}{\CurrentOption}%
  \ifin@
    \expandafter\bbl@tempa\CurrentOption\bbl@tempa
  \else
    \edef\bbl@language@opts{%
      \ifx\bbl@language@opts\@empty\else\bbl@language@opts,\fi
      \CurrentOption}%
  \fi}
\ProcessOptions*
\def\bbl@sh@string#1{%
  \ifx#1\@empty\else
    \ifx#1t\string~%
    \else\ifx#1c\string,%
    \else\string#1%
    \fi\fi
    \expandafter\bbl@sh@string
  \fi}
\ifx\bbl@opt@shorthands\@nnil
  \def\bbl@ifshorthand#1#2#3{#2}%
\else\ifx\bbl@opt@shorthands\@empty
  \def\bbl@ifshorthand#1#2#3{#3}%
\else
  \def\bbl@ifshorthand#1{%
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{\string#1}{\bbl@opt@shorthands}%
    \ifin@
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi}
  \edef\bbl@opt@shorthands{%
    \expandafter\bbl@sh@string\bbl@opt@shorthands\@empty}%

  \bbl@ifshorthand{'}%
    {\PassOptionsToPackage{activeacute}{babel}}{}
  \bbl@ifshorthand{`}%
    {\PassOptionsToPackage{activegrave}{babel}}{}
\fi\fi
\ifx\bbl@opt@headfoot\@nnil\else
  \g@addto@macro\@resetactivechars{%
    \set@typeset@protect
    \expandafter\select@language@x\expandafter{\bbl@opt@headfoot}%
    \let\protect\noexpand}
\fi
\@ifundefined{bbl@opt@safe}{\def\bbl@opt@safe{BR}}{}
\ifx\bbl@opt@main\@nnil\else
  \edef\bbl@language@opts{%
    \ifx\bbl@language@opts\@empty\else\bbl@language@opts,\fi
      \bbl@opt@main}
\fi
\ifx\bbl@languages\@undefined\else
  \begingroup
    \catcode`\^^I=12
    \@ifpackagewith{babel}{showlanguages}{%
      \begingroup
        \def\bbl@elt#1#2#3#4{\wlog{#2^^I#1^^I#3^^I#4}}%
        \wlog{<*languages>}%
        \bbl@languages
        \wlog{</languages>}%
      \endgroup}{}
  \endgroup
  \def\bbl@elt#1#2#3#4{%
    \ifnum#2=\z@
      \gdef\bbl@nulllanguage{#1}%
      \def\bbl@elt##1##2##3##4{}%
    \fi}%
  \bbl@languages
\fi
\let\bbl@afterlang\relax
\let\BabelModifiers\relax
\let\bbl@loaded\@empty
\def\bbl@load@language#1{%
  \InputIfFileExists{#1.ldf}%
    {\edef\bbl@loaded{\CurrentOption
       \ifx\bbl@loaded\@empty\else,\bbl@loaded\fi}%
     \expandafter\let\expandafter\bbl@afterlang
        \csname\CurrentOption.ldf-h@@k\endcsname
     \expandafter\let\expandafter\BabelModifiers
        \csname bbl@mod@\CurrentOption\endcsname}%
    {\bbl@error{%
       Unknow option `\CurrentOption'. Either you misspelled it\\%
       or the language definition file \CurrentOption.ldf was not found}{%
       Valid options are: shorthands=..., KeepShorthandsActive,\\%
       activeacute, activegrave, noconfigs, safe=, main=, math=\\%
       headfoot=, strings=, config=, or a language name.}}}
\DeclareOption{acadian}{\bbl@load@language{frenchb}}
\DeclareOption{afrikaans}{\bbl@load@language{dutch}}
\DeclareOption{american}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
\DeclareOption{australian}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
\DeclareOption{austrian}{\bbl@load@language{germanb}}
\DeclareOption{bahasa}{\bbl@load@language{bahasai}}
\DeclareOption{bahasai}{\bbl@load@language{bahasai}}
\DeclareOption{bahasam}{\bbl@load@language{bahasam}}
\DeclareOption{brazil}{\bbl@load@language{portuges}}
\DeclareOption{brazilian}{\bbl@load@language{portuges}}
\DeclareOption{british}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
\DeclareOption{canadian}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
\DeclareOption{canadien}{\bbl@load@language{frenchb}}
\DeclareOption{francais}{\bbl@load@language{frenchb}}
\DeclareOption{french}{\bbl@load@language{frenchb}}%
\DeclareOption{german}{\bbl@load@language{germanb}}
\DeclareOption{hebrew}{%
  \input{rlbabel.def}%
  \bbl@load@language{hebrew}}
\DeclareOption{hungarian}{\bbl@load@language{magyar}}
\DeclareOption{indon}{\bbl@load@language{bahasai}}
\DeclareOption{indonesian}{\bbl@load@language{bahasai}}
\DeclareOption{lowersorbian}{\bbl@load@language{lsorbian}}
\DeclareOption{malay}{\bbl@load@language{bahasam}}
\DeclareOption{meyalu}{\bbl@load@language{bahasam}}
\DeclareOption{naustrian}{\bbl@load@language{ngermanb}}
\DeclareOption{newzealand}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
\DeclareOption{ngerman}{\bbl@load@language{ngermanb}}
\DeclareOption{nynorsk}{\bbl@load@language{norsk}}
\DeclareOption{polutonikogreek}{%
  \bbl@load@language{greek}%
  \languageattribute{greek}{polutoniko}}
\DeclareOption{portuguese}{\bbl@load@language{portuges}}
\DeclareOption{russian}{\bbl@load@language{russianb}}
\DeclareOption{UKenglish}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
\DeclareOption{ukrainian}{\bbl@load@language{ukraineb}}
\DeclareOption{uppersorbian}{\bbl@load@language{usorbian}}
\DeclareOption{USenglish}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
\ifx\bbl@opt@config\@nnil
  \@ifpackagewith{babel}{noconfigs}{}%
    {\InputIfFileExists{bblopts.cfg}%
      {\typeout{*************************************^^J%
               * Local config file bblopts.cfg used^^J%
               *}}%
      {}}%
\else
  \InputIfFileExists{\bbl@opt@config.cfg}%
    {\typeout{*************************************^^J%
             * Local config file \bbl@opt@config.cfg used^^J%
             *}}%
    {\bbl@error{%
       Local config file `\bbl@opt@config.cfg' not found}{%
       Perhaps you misspelled it.}}%
\fi
\bbl@for\bbl@tempa\bbl@language@opts{%
  \@ifundefined{ds@\bbl@tempa}%
    {\edef\bbl@tempb{%
       \noexpand\DeclareOption
         {\bbl@tempa}%
         {\noexpand\bbl@load@language{\bbl@tempa}}}%
     \bbl@tempb}%
     \@empty}
\bbl@for\bbl@tempa\@classoptionslist{%
  \@ifundefined{ds@\bbl@tempa}%
    {\IfFileExists{\bbl@tempa.ldf}%
      {\edef\bbl@tempb{%
         \noexpand\DeclareOption
           {\bbl@tempa}%
           {\noexpand\bbl@load@language{\bbl@tempa}}}%
       \bbl@tempb}%
      \@empty}%
    \@empty}
\ifx\bbl@opt@main\@nnil\else
  \expandafter
  \let\expandafter\bbl@loadmain\csname ds@\bbl@opt@main\endcsname
  \DeclareOption{\bbl@opt@main}{}
\fi
\def\AfterBabelLanguage#1{%
  \bbl@ifsamestring\CurrentOption{#1}{\global\bbl@add\bbl@afterlang}{}}
\DeclareOption*{}
\ProcessOptions*
\ifx\bbl@opt@main\@nnil
  \edef\bbl@tempa{\@classoptionslist,\bbl@language@opts}
  \let\bbl@tempc\@empty
  \bbl@for\bbl@tempb\bbl@tempa{%
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\bbl@tempb,}{,\bbl@loaded,}%
    \ifin@\edef\bbl@tempc{\bbl@tempb}\fi}
  \def\bbl@tempa#1,#2\@nnil{\def\bbl@tempb{#1}}
  \expandafter\bbl@tempa\bbl@loaded,\@nnil
  \ifx\bbl@tempb\bbl@tempc\else
    \bbl@warning{%
      Last declared language option is `\bbl@tempc,\\%
      but the last processed one was `\bbl@tempb'.\\%
      The main language cannot be set as both a global\\%
      and a package option. Use `main=\bbl@tempc' as\\%
      option. Reported}%
  \fi
\else
  \DeclareOption{\bbl@opt@main}{\bbl@loadmain}
  \ExecuteOptions{\bbl@opt@main}
  \DeclareOption*{}
  \ProcessOptions*
\fi
\def\AfterBabelLanguage{%
  \bbl@error
    {Too late for \string\AfterBabelLanguage}%
    {Languages have been loaded, so I can do nothing}}
\ifx\bbl@main@language\@undefined
  \bbl@error{%
    You haven't specified a language option}{%
    You need to specify a language, either as a global option\\%
    or as an optional argument to the \string\usepackage\space
    command;\\%
    You shouldn't try to proceed from here, type x to quit.}
\fi
%%
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
\endinput
    %%
    %% End of file `babel.sty'.
```

In `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel`, I have for instance the file `danish.sty`.

I don't understand the error when running latex.

Can anyone help or guide me in a direction?

I did follow the instructions from a similar problem, but without any luck.
I tried: `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-danish` and I got among other things this:

```
E: Package 'texlive-lang-danish' has no installation candidate
```

It works with a diffrent version of texlive.

Comment: After removing the other typos in your MWE, it compiles without problem. Could you give the contents of `\listfiles`? See [Which package version am I using?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764)

Comment: I did that with this result. This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2014.1.11)  15 APR 2014 08:04
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**testnotat.tex
(./testnotat.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)

Comment: The file `danish.ldf` is in `texlive-lang-european`. [Debian](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) or [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) both provide a search formular "Search the contents of packages" that help in identifying the right distribution package.