# Caption package in subfigures

Tags: captions, subfloats

In [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats) it is suggested that to have subfigures, one should use the `subcaption` package.

However, in the given example, the `caption` package is also included. Is it necessary here? If so, what is it for? Usually, including captions (e.g. `\caption{Pictures of animals}`) does not need the `caption` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not needed in the example as the (current) [`subcaption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) code includes

```
\RequirePackage{caption}[2012/03/25] % needs v3.3 or newer
```

which would load [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) if it is not loaded already. You'll notice the same thing when you do not load `caption` but [include `\listfiles` in your preamble and check your `.log` file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764).

And yes, there is no need to load `caption` in order to use `\caption`. It provides a host of features though...