# How to add local textmf directories without using MikTeX Console or via mo_admin

Tags: miktex

I'm trying to automate the MikTeX configuration without the use of any GUI, is there any possible way to add local `textmf` into root directories maybe by just editing some `.ini` files or via the command prompt?

Comment: Command prompt: `initexmf --register-root=DIR` and `initexmf --unregister-root=DIR`. `DIR` is the path to the local `texmf`.

Comment: See also https://docs.miktex.org/manual/initexmf.html (which I only found because esdd gave the answer). Unfortunately https://miktex.org/kb/texmf-roots and https://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html (which I found before) only mention the console. Maybe you could ask the MikTeX maintainer to mention the command line solutions more prominently.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187414/2388

Comment: On unix-like systems, including macosx, you should be able to do this by adding the directories t the environment variable `$TEXMFLOCAL`. Not sure if this works with PCs and hence MikTeX... Perhaps not, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118793/miktex-does-not-use-texmflocal-environment-variable

Comment: @esdd `initexmf --register-root=DIR` actually work out just fine, thanks alot.