# Spacing in a two-column document in ShareLatex

Tags: two-column, sharelatex

I have the following source code. When I compile it in Emacs+AUCTex I have the expected result, but when I compile it in ShareLaTeX there are huge gaps between paragraphs as ,I can only guess, ShareLaTeX tries to occupy the whole column space. Why is this happening? How can I fix it? I suspect that it might be a bug.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage
[
    top=0.7in,
    bottom=1.2in,
    left=0.8in,
    right=0.8in,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\setmainfont
[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*,
    BoldFont=*Bold,
    ItalicFont=*It,
    BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
    Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Name}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\lipsum[1]

\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\section{Section}

\lipsum[1-2]

Sample text here!

\end{multicols*}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

**In Emacs**

[image]

**In ShareLaTeX**

[image]

Comment: Like at the `**File List**` on each system (see [Which package version am I using?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764)).

Comment: @Werner the problem is in ShareLaTeX obviously as Emacs' output is the expected. Can I find the version of packages in ShareLaTeX?

Comment: In the usual way: Add `\listfiles` to the preamble, recompile, click on Logs and output files, View Raw Logs, find `**File List**`.

Comment: @Werner I did that and there is no File List generated. As it is online I think that the packages are updated and are the same to all computers.

Comment: You'd be surprised at how out-of-date those online services can be.

Comment: @SeanAllred is there anything that I can do? I have the same result in multiple computers and with multiple documents.

Comment: I can't say that I know.  *If* the online service is out-of-date, I don't suppose there's much you can do besides raise the issue.  I believe ShareLaTeX is on GitHub these days.  Otherwise, you can always bring your own distribution up-to-date to ensure that you're not the one lagging behind.  As a band-aid, my first thought was `\vfill`.  (Also, I removed the [tag:emacs] and [tag:auctex] tags; the editor has nothing to do with the problem here.)

Comment: @SeanAllred yes those tags were not relevant. For the same reason I edited the title.

Comment: Does the problem still persist?