# Wrong caption using subfloat command

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I am using the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}       
\usepackage{graphicx,rotating}
\usepackage{subfig}
\linespread{1.15}                   
\setlength\parindent{0pt}           
\usepackage{enumitem} \setlist[itemize,enumerate]{leftmargin=*}         \usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol} \setlength{\columnsep}{0.25in} 

\usepackage[super]{nth} % enable typing 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, bookmarks=true, %backref,
            %bookmarksnumbered=false,
            breaklinks={true},
            linkcolor={blue},
            anchorcolor={black},
            citecolor={green},
            filecolor={black},
            menucolor={blue},
            plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,
            urlcolor={blue}]{hyperref}

\usepackage[left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle



\begin{figure} \centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=7in]{TF_15d1b}} \\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=7in]{TF_15d1c}}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure} \centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=7in]{TF_15d1b}} \\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=7in]{TF_15d1c}}
\end{figure}  



\end{document}
```

The subcaptions for the first three subfloats are ok as (a) and (b) However, for the next set of figures (subfloats) the captions instead of starting with (a), they start with (c) and continue as (d). I really cannot see what I am doing wrong. Can some one suggest something. I am using MacTex 2014 with Texmaker.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Perhaps this is a version issue? See [Which package version am I using?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764) Include the contents in your `.log` *after* `**File List**` in your post as an [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/241493/edit).

Comment: Werner I am not sure how to get what you are asking. I am using MacTex 2014.

Comment: I see (a) (b) and (a) (b) in your MWE with TexLive 2014

Comment: Does precisely that code compile with different results for you?

Comment: Note that `subfig` doesn't behave well with `hyperref` and that `subcaption` is to be preferred in this case, unless your document class is not compatible with the `caption` package (which is not the case with `article`).

Comment: @ cfr yes the code compiles differently

Comment: Just as a shot in the dark, try adding \stepcounter{figure} or in each figure, before the subfloats.  Or try to find out what counter is being used by \subfloat and reset it each time.