# Environment \pspicture only works with single slide in beamer?

Tags: beamer, pstricks, compiling, bounding-box

I'm trying to use pstricks in beamer, and need to compile it with pdflatex.
Weirdly, the code works when I have a single frame (see MWE below) but as soon as I add a second frame (i.e. uncomment line 4), my Ghostscript goes crazy it seems. Why is that??

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks,auto-pst-pdf} 
\begin{document}
%\frame{frame1}
\frame{
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
    \psdot(.4,.3)
  \end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Sample console output:

```
Last OS error: Invalid argument
Current file position is 116155
GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.

!!! Warning: Empty Bounding Box is returned by Ghostscript!
!!!   Page 1: 0 0 0 0
!!! Either there is a problem with the page or with Ghostscript.
!!! Recovery is tried by embedding the page in its original size.
```

Comment: No problem here. [What file versions are you running?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764)

Comment: @Werner `PSTricks' v2.54a  <2014/05/19> (tvz)

Comment: [Update your distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764) and try again. I am running TeX Live 2015 with the most up-to-date packages, and there's no problem.

Comment: you should update Ghostscript

Comment: @Herbert I just updated Ghostscript to 9.16, but that didn't help. I don't have time to update the entire distribution right now, but that's what I'll try next. Thanks though!

Comment: try to run your document with `xelatex` and _not loading_ `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: Works fine with Texlive2017

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as not reproducible with current version of texlive/ghostscripte