# Appendix references failing with tables

Tags: tables

I'm using a LaTeX template to produce my master thesis and I've encountered the following problem in appendix with tables.

In `tese.tex` where the document is set I have the following:

```
\begin{appendices}
\begin{appendix}
    \pagenumbering{bychapter}
    \input{Appendices/appendixA.tex}     
    \cleardoublepage
\end{appendix}
\end{appendices}
```

And in `appendixA.tex`:

```
\fancychapter{Title of AppendixA}
\label{ap:a}
```

And then in my introduction for example I write `\ref{ap:a}` and everything works just fine.

The problem appears when I had a table to the appendix, for example

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    &  &  \\
    &  &  \\
    &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Now if try to do `\ref{ap:a}` I get `` Reference `ap:a' on page 4 undefined ``.

Other important things are that I can reference the table (doing `\ref{my-label}` works perfectly and if add another appendix, let's image:

```
\begin{appendices}
\begin{appendix}
    \pagenumbering{bychapter}
    \input{Appendices/appendixA.tex} 
    \input{Appendices/appendixB.tex}       
    \cleardoublepage
\end{appendix}
\end{appendices}
```

Where `appendixB.tex` may be a copy of `appendixA.tex` but with a different label, then the problem migrates to appendix B and I start being abbe to reference appendix A.

All this example files I've named here, along with other configuration and tex files are in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/themiguelamador/ThesisIST). I've created an [issue](https://github.com/themiguelamador/ThesisIST/issues/5) for this but so far I got nothing.

**Update**

According to comments added the file list adding `\listfiles` to the preamble, and my `.log` has the following:

```
 *File List*
      01.thesis.cls    2011/08/23
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
indentfirst.sty    1995/11/23 v1.03 Indent first paragraph (DPC)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
    ulem.sty    2012/05/18
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
    epsf.sty    
      00.textpos.sty    2007/03/30 v1.7d
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  helvet.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS) 
 amsmath.sty    2016/06/28 v2.15d AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2015/03/04 v2.20.2
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
00.Definitions/packages.tex
   babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of b
abel
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
portuges.ldf    2008/03/18 v1.2q Portuguese support from the babel system
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX file
datetime.sty    2015/03/20 v2.60 Date Time Package
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
fmtcount.sty    2015/05/05 v3.01
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
fcprefix.sty    2012/09/28
fcnumparser.sty    2012/09/28
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
fc-english.def    2013/08/17
fc-portuges.def    2014/06/09
datetime-defaults.sty    2013/09/10
latexsym.sty    1998/08/17 v2.2e Standard LaTeX package (lasy symbols)
multirow.sty    
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
   color.sty    2016/07/10 v1.1e Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
supertabular.sty    2004/02/20 v4.1e the supertabular environment
pdflscape.sty    2016/05/14 v0.11 Display of landscape pages in PDF (HO)
  lscape.sty    2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
  epsfig.sty    1999/02/16 v1.7a (e)psfig emulation (SPQR)
subfigure.sty    2002/07/30 v2.1.4 subfigure package
subfigure.cfg
 dcolumn.sty    2014/10/28 v1.06 decimal alignment package (DPC)
      bm.sty    2016/07/07 v1.2b Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
rotating.sty    2016/05/22 v2.16c rotated objects in LaTeX
 caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
 acronym.sty    2015/03/21 v1.41 Support for acronyms (Tobias Oetiker)
  suffix.sty    2006/07/15 1.5a Variant command support
 xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
appendix.sty    2009/09/02 v1.2b extra appendix facilities
  chappg.sty    2006/05/09 v2.1b page numbering by chapter number pages by chap
ter (or other unit)
      00.extra_functions.sty    
 minitoc.sty    2015/07/13 v61 Package minitoc
 mtcmess.sty    2006/03/14
    tese.mtc0
 english.mld    2006/01/13
 english.mld    2006/01/13
     bbm.sty    1999/03/15 V 1.2 provides fonts for set symbols - TH
verbatim.sty    2014/10/28 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
hyperref.sty    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
      00.symlist.sty    2008/03/11 v1.1 Symbol List package
00.Definitions/pagesetup.tex
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
geometry.cfg
fancyhdr.sty    2016/09/06 3.8 Extensive control of page headers and footers
   t1phv.fd    2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for T1/phv.
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
    tese.out
    tese.out
0.Inicio/1.cover.tex
Figures/Cover/istnewlogo.pdf
Figures/Cover/coverimage.jpg
0.Inicio/2.citation.tex
0.Inicio/3.Acknowledgments.tex
0.Inicio/4.Abstract.tex
0.Inicio/5.Keywords.tex
0.Inicio/4.Resumo.tex
0.Inicio/5.PalavrasChave.tex
0.Inicio/6.Tables.tex
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
   ulasy.fd    1998/08/17 v2.2e LaTeX symbol font definitions
0.Inicio/7.Acronim.tex
0.Inicio/8.symbols.tex
1.Introduction/main.tex
   t1pbk.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/pbk.
1.Introduction/1.motivation.tex
1.Introduction/2.state.tex
1.Introduction/3.contributions.tex
1.Introduction/4.outline.tex
2.Chapter/main.tex
2.Chapter/1.sectiona.tex
Figures/2.Chapter/dummy.pdf
2.Chapter/2.sectionb.tex
  omsphv.fd    
99.Conclusions/conclusions.tex
    tese.bbl
Appendices/appendixA.tex
 ***********
```

Comment: I downloaded your thesis and was able to compile it without problem. References to `ap:a` worked from what I downloaded, and also after adding your `table` example to `appendixA.tex`. So I'm unable to replicate your problem.

Comment: How about [updating your distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764)? Do you know whether it's up-to-date?

Comment: Even after adding the table to the appendix and ``\ref{ap:a}`` in one of the files your compilation didn't gave warnings? I've tried in two machines, one didn't had LaTeX so I installed everything up to date and as soon as I add the table the reference changes from "A" to "??".

Comment: There was another user in the GitHub issue that was able to replicate the problem.

Comment: Yes, I added a table and `\ref{ap:a}` remained in tact with a correct hyperlink to Appendix A. Your next step might be to add `\listfiles` to your preamble and include in this post what you have under `*File List*` in your `.log`. See [Which package version am I using?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764)

Comment: updated the question, but I don't know for what to look.

Comment: Do you have a `booktabs.sty` in the folder you're working with, or perhaps a local distribution? You version shows up as `2005/04/14 v1.61803`. I have `2016/04/27 v1.618033`.

Comment: You are also loading an unknown `bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1`, which I don't have. Finally, there's a `geometry.cfg` loaded as well as `fancyhdr.sty`, both of which don't have any versions associated with them. I'm not showing any loading of `geometry.cfg`, and my `fancyhdr.sty` is `2016/09/06 3.8`.

Comment: I updated the logfile. I copied the wrong log file, the one you saw was my thesis document and not the template. While what you referenced in the second comment was resolved, the ``booktabs`` didn't. There is no such file and I use miktex package manager to uninstall and install again the package but the version that is on the repository is from 2005.

Comment: You can [download the latest version from CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) (and compile the `.ins` to produce a `.sty`) and keep that in the folder you're working with. Local files supersede repository/installed ones.

Comment: Done, but unfortunately the issue remains even with the updated package..

Comment: Well, if I can't replicate the problem, I can't solve it. Good luck.