# How to make only cited bibitems appear?

Tags: bibliographies

When citing items using BibTeX, only the cited items show up in the bibliography (unless you use `\nocite{*}`).
Can I have the same effect for normal `\bibitems` that are at the end of my `.tex` file?
(I have a long list that I use for several longer reports.)

Comment: If the bibliography items are listed verbatim as `\bibitem`s and you're not using a bibliography manager like BibTeX or BibLaTeX, then there's not much you can do... all the items will be set regardless of whether they're `\cite`d or not. As such, removing `\nocite{*}` would not make any difference. "Not much" means there might be other methods, but it's just not as easy.

Comment: Perhaps we need to see which packages you're loading (see [Which package version am I using?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764)), since solutions may have to be compatible with your setup.

Comment: The usual method is to make your collection of references as a `.bib` file (bibtex "database") and then the job of extracting just the used citations is exactly what bibtex (and now biber) are designed to do. `\nocite` does nothing if you are not using bibtex.

Comment: @Werner I see, I didn't know! I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Short answer: No. If you are doing stuff manually, you have to do stuff manually.

Comment: Is there are a specific reason why you do not want to use bibtex/biblatex/.. ?  Because even though this might in principle be possible (if not using latex then using simple scripting) it will be unnecessarily cumbersome, because there already is a solution for this.

Comment: [Manually managing references](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References)

Comment: @Johannes But why? This seems like such a simple thing to solve, and I like to format each reference differently, the way I like. I don't think I would be the only one with this problem.

Comment: The solution is BibTeX or the modern combination of Biblatex and biber. That ensures a consistently formatted bibliography.

Comment: A manual solution, but you can use the `refcheck` package to quickly identify which items from the bibliography are actually cited, and then comment out those you don't use.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I knew about this one, which, I think, also shows the need for a solution to my problem. I don't understand why I'm not allowed to have a long list of bibitems formatted the way I like them, and each time cite only the ones I want to cite, without the need of going through the whole list with refcheck.

Comment: @domotorp The way the `bibliography` works is that it _typesets_ the content (`\bibitem` entries): it was never intended to be selective about what is there.

Comment: @Joseph I can understand that that was the original intention, but what I'm asking for seems like a simple modification.

Comment: @domotorp Not really, as there's no end marker for `\bibitem` so collecting stuff up would be non-trivial. Moreover, the interest in developing such a solution is likely to be low as using a `.bib` database and either BibTeX or Biber is very common and is selective.

Comment: @Joseph Well, my `\bibitems` always end in another `\bibitem` or with `\end{bibliography}`. And trust me, most of my co-authors don't use BibTeX and would appreciate such a solution. We are simple mathematicians who are terrible at coding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are prepared to accept that `\bibitem` should be ended by a blank line, then you can modify some of the code from `source2e` and `refcheck` to make this work.  You have run latex three times to get the correct numbering in the text.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\@@citation@@=\citation

\renewcommand{\citation}[1]{\@@citation@@{#1}%
\@for\@tempa:=#1\do{\@ifundefined{cit@\@tempa}%
  {\global\@namedef{cit@\@tempa}{}}{}}%
}

\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2#3\par{%
  \@ifundefined{cit@#2}{}{\item[\@biblabel{#1}\hfill]}%
  \if@filesw
      {\let\protect\noexpand
       \immediate
       \write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#2}{#1}}}\fi\ignorespaces
  \@ifundefined{cit@#2}{}{#3}}
\def\@bibitem#1#2\par{%
  \@ifundefined{cit@#1}{}{\item}%
  \if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
    {\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces
  \@ifundefined{cit@#1}{}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test a citation \cite{one} and another \cite{three}.  Also one more
for luck: \cite{five}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{one} Reference one.

\bibitem{two} Reference two.

\bibitem[Special]{three} Reference three.

\bibitem{four} Reference four.

\bibitem{five} Reference five.

\bibitem[Unusual]{six} Reference six.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The first part of the code is `refcheck`s modification to the `\cite` command so that use of a bibitem is recorded.  The second part is a modification of the core latex `\bibitem`, so that it always records the label in the `.aux` file, but only prints out the body if the item has been cited.

If you need to use this with `hyperref` so there are links to the bibliography, then the coding has to be adapted to `hyperref`'s versions on `\@lbibitem` and `\@bibitem`, since `hyperref` simply overwrites the current definition.  This is given as follows, notice the positioning of the loading of the `hyperref` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\@@citation@@=\citation

\renewcommand{\citation}[1]{\@@citation@@{#1}%
\@for\@tempa:=#1\do{\@ifundefined{cit@\@tempa}%
  {\global\@namedef{cit@\@tempa}{}}{}}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2#3\par{%
  \@ifundefined{cit@#2}{}{\@skiphyperreftrue
  \H@item[%
    \ifx\Hy@raisedlink\@empty
      \hyper@anchorstart{cite.#2\@extra@b@citeb}%
        \@BIBLABEL{#1}%
      \hyper@anchorend
    \else
      \Hy@raisedlink{%
        \hyper@anchorstart{cite.#2\@extra@b@citeb}\hyper@anchorend
      }%
      \@BIBLABEL{#1}%
    \fi
    \hfill
  ]%
  \@skiphyperreffalse}%
  \if@filesw
    \begingroup
      \let\protect\noexpand
      \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\bibcite{#2}{#1}%
      }%
    \endgroup
  \fi
  \ignorespaces
  \@ifundefined{cit@#2}{}{#3}}

\def\@bibitem#1#2\par{%
  \@ifundefined{cit@#1}{}{\@skiphyperreftrue\H@item\@skiphyperreffalse
  \Hy@raisedlink{%
    \hyper@anchorstart{cite.#1\@extra@b@citeb}\relax\hyper@anchorend
    }}%
  \if@filesw
    \begingroup
      \let\protect\noexpand
      \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{\@listctr}}%
      }%
    \endgroup
  \fi
  \ignorespaces
  \@ifundefined{cit@#1}{}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test a citation \cite{one} and another \cite{three}.  Also one more
for luck: \cite{five}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{one} Reference one.

\bibitem{two} Reference two.

\bibitem[Special]{three} Reference three.

\bibitem{four} Reference four.

\bibitem{five} Reference five.

\bibitem[Unusual]{six} Reference six.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! I still have one error message tough. Should I have a blank line before and after each `\bibitem`?

Comment: OK, after half an hour I've figured out that I need a linebreak also after the last `\bibitem` which was there in bibliography.tex, but after I input it in the main file, it apparently gets ignored, so a linebreak is needed in the main file after the input.

Comment: You just need each `\bibitem` to end with a blank line (or a `\par`)

Comment: I've just noticed a slight problem with this approach; when I click on a reference in the pdf, it doesn't take me to the cited item.

Comment: @domotorp Well, to get clickable links you have to load the `hyperref` package.  As usual make sure you do this as late as possible in your preamble, in particular _after_ the modifications above.  Then it works for me.

Comment: I tried and the links also work for me if I swap the order, but all citations are shown.

Comment: @domotorp Update for working with hyperref now provided.

Answer (score 2):

You could change your input format to put the text in an argument. Then it is rather easy to suppress one entry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd\@citex{\csgdef{used@cite@#2}{x}}{}{\failed}
\newcommand\checkbibentry[2]{\ifcsdef{used@cite@#1}{\bibitem{#1}{#2}}{}}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

\cite{a} \cite{c}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\checkbibentry{a}{some text to a}

\checkbibentry{b}{some text to b}

\checkbibentry{c}{some text to c}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works well for me for \cite{A} but not for \cite{A,B,...}, whenever I cite more than one ref at once they seem to be omitted as well. How does one adapt the code to ensure this works? Thanks a lot