# Bold name and year in bibliography don't work with TeXstudio

Tags: biblatex

I would like the name and year in my bibliography to be bold. For this I used the following LaTeX code:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, natbib=true, citestyle=numeric, style=numeric, sorting=nty]{biblatex}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
\renewcommand*\mkbibnamefirst[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*\mkbibnamelast[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*\mkbibnameprefix[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*\mkbibnameaffix[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{parens}{\mkbibbold{\mkbibparens{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{author}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
```

I write my text on two computers and in both cases I use TeXstudio (with MikTeX). The problem is that on machines (A) the names and years are as desired bold and not on computer (B).

Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think it's a TeXstudio problem. Check if your MiKTeX distributions are updated on both machine A and B. You can see if you're using the same package versions on the two machines adding  `\listfiles` to your preamble and comparing the logs, see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/101651

Comment: @CarLaTeX I had also thought of this, so I had the packages updated with MiKtex Update (Admin)

Comment: Have you tried `\listfiles`? What do the logs say?

Comment: You may have to update the packages with 'MikTeX Update' in the user version if you installed `biblatex` as user. The code above looks like pre-3.3 code, for current versions of `biblatex` you should apply some modifications, see [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864).

Comment: Any news here? Did you check the versions involved? Did you do an update? Can you check if the `.log` files between the two machines differ? Does computer (B) have anything further to say about warnings and errors?

Comment: I have decided to vote to close as a duplicate of the `biblatex` 3.3 name formatting question as that is the only thing 'wrong' with your code at the moment. If you have any more information or a proper MWE, don't hesitate to edit your question and it can be reopened.