# Page numbers only on even pages

Tags: page-numbering

I need to put page numbers only on even pages:

- Page 1, no page number.
- Page 2, number 1.
- Page 3, no page number.
- Page 4, number 2.
- Page 5, no page number.
- Page 6, number 3.

I guess I need to mess a bit with the page numbering system like a `\renewcommand{\thepage}` that would divide the page by two or check if it's even?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
No page number \newpage Should be 1 \newpage
No page number \newpage Should be 2 \newpage
No page number \newpage Should be 3 \newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: What have you got so far? Post code for a minimal document with page numbers on all pages and somebody will show you how to make them show only on the even ones.

Comment: I thought of writing a code but I just want a toy example, meaning I only have like \documentclass{article} \begin{document} ... \end{document}. This basic code already displays the pages at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Suppose you have a `\section` that starts on the third physical page (the page without number that comes right before the page numbered “2”): what page number should show up in the ToC entry for this section?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the `fancyhdr` package to redefine the `plain` page style. The logic is simple. The page number is not printed if it's odd. If it's even, the page number is divided by two and then printed.

Note that this doesn't change actual page number, so cross references and table of contents will be wrong if you use them. But I'm not sure how to avoid this if you are not numbering every page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\newcount\halfpage
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{%
    \ifodd\c@page
    \else
      \halfpage=\c@page
      \divide\halfpage by 2
      \@arabic{\halfpage}%
    \fi}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can perform a calculation for the even pages and divide the page number by 2:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,xfp}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \ifodd\value{page}\else
    \inteval{\value{page} / 2}% Divide even page number by 2
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule

\begin{document}

No page number \newpage Should be 1 \newpage
No page number \newpage Should be 2 \newpage
No page number \newpage Should be 3 \newpage

\end{document}
```

Note though that `\thepage` (the original page number) will be stored for every `\label`, as well as in the ToC. If you want to be able to use the new page number in these as well, more work needs to be done.

Comment: This code gives me "! Undefined control sequence." in
\f@nch@ocf ->\ifodd \value {page}\else \inteval 
                                                {\value {page} / 2}\fi \strut 
l.16 No page number \newpage Should be 1 \newpage.
Humm

Comment: @RobertVandenEynde: Are you including the [`xfp` package](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) like I did?

Comment: Yep, I copy pasted your code.

Comment: @RobertVandenEynde: What version of the [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) are you using? I'm using one dated `2018-05-12`; the latest available.

Comment: How do I find out the version ? Btw I'm on Ubuntu 2017.10 so probably not latex versions, my latex packages are installed with apt install texlive. I tried googling "linux bash check ctan latex version package" or similar but no real success.

Comment: @RobertVandenEyndeb: See [Which package version am I using?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764) it suggests adding `\listfiles` to your preamble and checking your `.log` file.

Comment: _On en apprend tout les jours_ :) xfp.sty    2017/07/19 L3 Floating point unit, without any surprise for my Ubuntu 2017.10, did they change the interface recently?

Comment: @RobertVandenEynde: Since it forms part of the LaTeX3 development, it's experimental until further notice. As such, things may change between releases. `\inteval` seemed to form part of the 2017-09-18 release ([announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.text.tex/xfp%7Csort:date/comp.text.tex/XydsHKodun8/xCOFnDy0BQAJ)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where `thepage` is redefined (no need for a custom header). This even works with `hyperref` and shows the desired page number in the PDF bookmarks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}%% optional
\providecommand{\texorpdfstring}[2]{#1} %% makes hyperref package optional

%% Format that you want to see on the pages and in references:
\def\pageformatTexEven{\arabic{HalfPage}}
\def\pageformatTexOdd{}%% Note: this will also not show a page number in references and toc
%% Will be shown in pdf bookmarks:
\def\pageformatInternalEven{\arabic{HalfPage}}
%\def\pageformatInternalOdd{\arabic{HalfPage}b}
\def\pageformatInternalOdd{\arabic{HalfPage}}

%% Manually set the page number on every page:
\usepackage{everypage}
\makeatletter
\newcount\halfpage
\newcounter{HalfPage}
\AddEverypageHook{%
    \halfpage=\c@page%
    \divide\halfpage by 2%
    \setcounter{HalfPage}{\halfpage}%
    \ifodd\c@page%
        \global\def\thepageformat{%
            \texorpdfstring{\pageformatTexOdd}{\pageformatInternalOdd}%
        }%
    \else%
        \global\def\thepageformat{%
            \texorpdfstring{\pageformatTexEven}{\pageformatInternalEven}%
        }%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thepageformat}


\begin{document}
    %% Just for better visualization:
    \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\Huge\thepageformat}

    {\Huge \tableofcontents}
    \section{A} No page number \newpage \section{B} Should be 1 \newpage
    \section{C} No page number \newpage \section{D} Should be 2 \newpage
    \section{E} No page number \newpage \section{F} Should be 3 \newpage
\end{document}
```

A package like `fancyhdr` is only needed to suppress the page number if `\pageformatTexOdd` is defined to show a page number (for table of contents and references).