# how do I check the \listfiles command

Tags: pdftex, external-files

How do I check that the `\listfiles` command works?
When I give it in front of `\begin{document}` OR I delete it,
**no** difference appears to happen.

Comment: Related: [Which package version am I using?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\listfiles` puts its output into the log file (if your tex file is named `something.tex`, the log file will typically be named `something.log`). It also puts the output into the terminal (if you are compiling the document from a terminal).