# ERROR in "fillstyle=solid"

Tags: pstricks

I'm running pstricks and the toolchain "Latex + dvips + ps2pdf + view pdf".

1. The call of `fillstyle=solid` cause problem : the document compile but is cut just before the graphic !
2. If I change to `fillstyle=vlines` (for example), it *works* ... but with "vlines" I don't want!
3. If I modify the toolchain with XeLatex and `fillstyle=solid`, it's "ok" but *all* the `rput` text are put all together!!! It's illegible!
4. Here is a minimal code :

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\listfiles

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(6,6)
        \rput(0,3){ESSAI}
        \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red, linecolor=blue](-3,-2)(-6,-6)
        \psframe[fillstyle=vlines, hatchcolor=red](3,2)(6,6)
        \rput(0,0){ECHEC}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I have no idea of a solution
Code was OK a few month ago !
Perhap's a recent update of pstricks ?
Thanks
David
[Here is the log file on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YWV353dd)
Here is a part of my *log file* :

It's written :

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
inputenc.sty    2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
pstricks.sty    2020/06/11 v0.70 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   dvips.def    2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
pstricks.tex    2020/09/18 v3.01 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
  pst-fp.tex    2020/09/18 v3.01 `PST-fp' (hv)
l3backend-dvips.def    2020-09-24 L3 backend support: dvips
 ***********
```

`fillstyle=vlines, hatchcolor=white` works, but it's a bad solution !
Thanks
David

Comment: No problem compiling it on my machine. Can you also include your `.log` after adding [`\listfiles`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764) to your preamble?

Comment: No problem either with `xelatex`.

Comment: You should paste your `.log` as part of the post, or possibly to pastebin.com. I only have a more up-to-date `l3backend-dvips.def` (2021-01-09). If you're running TeX Live, do `tlmgr update --self --all` to update everything.

Comment: Thanks Werner ! But `tlmgr update --self --all` do :
```
USER@HOME:~$ tlmgr update --self --all
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: no self-updates for tlmgr available
tlmgr: no updates available
```
and
`l3backend-dvips.def` stay still to `2020-09-24 L3 backend support: dvips` ! How is it possible to update ? OK ! `tlmgr install --reinstall l3backend` works and, now, I have got : `l3backend-dvips.def 2021-01-09` ! but `fill

Comment: I can't replicate your issue, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Werner \& Bernard ! No solution for me ... I keep searching !

Comment: `\usepackage{tikz}` solved the problem !!! Don't know why ! It seems to be a temporary solution, before finding a better one !

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced with my machine.