# xparse error with TexShop

Tags: overleaf, texshop, xparse

This is a very strange question I encountered...so I am using the "NewDocumentCommand" from xparse. I have the following codes in my "test.sty" file (just a simple example):

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Test}{e{_}}{\mathbb{T}_{#1}}
```

I have the following codes in my .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,test}
\begin{document}
\[\Test_{n}\]
\end{document}
```

Now, if I run this using TexShop on my Mac, it shows the error message

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
./test.sty:3: LaTeX error: "xparse/unknown-argument-type"
! 
! Unknown argument type '_' replaced by 'm'.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  
                                                  
l.3 ...cumentCommand{\Test}{e{_}}{\mathbb{T}_{#1}}
                                                  
? 
                                                  
?
```

However, when I run it on overleaf, it goes through and produces the expected result. I also asked a friend to run this on his TexShop, and it also goes without error.

So, I guess the issue is not with my code, but with my TexShop. I updated it to the latest ver 4.68 but the problem persists. I tried to change some configurations/settings but I don't know what could be possibly related to this phenomenon. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  It looks like (from the formatting of the error message) that your local TeX installation is too old (the `e` argument type was added around 2018, I think).  You'll need to update

Comment: Please add `\listfiles` to your preamble and include the part of the `.log` that lists the package versions currently being used with your file. Also see [Which package version am I using?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764)

Comment: @Werner Oh yes...I did this and found that I had Texlive 2015 whose xparse package does not support argument type "e". I updated it to Texlive 2021 and solved the problem. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes indeed...I updated to Texlive 2021 and solved the problem. Previously I didn't know that this was different from updating Texshop. Thanks!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was caused by outdated software; solved with an update.

Comment: note that in texlive 2021 you don't need to load xparse at all here NewDocumentCommand is built in to the latex format.