# New conditional to test package version

Tags: macros, package-writing, documentclass-writing

By now, how should one write the code that does `if the package <package> is newer than <version>, do <thing A>; otherwise do <thing B>`?

*I'm aware of `\@ifpackagelater`, but I seem to remember once saw an entry in an article of LaTeX News that (by the year 2021?) there is a new reliable way to do so, yet now I cannot recall the detail or where did I see this* `:(`

Comment: There is `\IfPackageAtLeastTF` which is just a copy of `\@ifpackagelater`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/which-package-version-am-i-using#comment1606646_13309 it's not like that I don't make the effort to keep old questions up to date...

Comment: Ah, thank you all, that's it, the LaTeX News Issue 32 :)